# Get latest date value based on month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following records. It is broken based on username, date and testscore.

```
Username     date                          testscore
mike         2016-11-30 23:41:10.143       1
mike         2016-11-27 23:41:11.143       12
mike         2016-11-24 23:41:11.143       16
john         2016-11-28 23:41:11.143       7
john         2016-11-25 23:42:11.143       12
john         2016-11-25 23:42:11.143       7
mike         2016-10-30 23:41:10.143       1
mike         2016-10-27 23:41:11.143       5
mike         2016-10-24 23:41:11.143       16
john         2016-10-28 23:41:11.143       12
john         2016-10-25 23:42:11.143       8
john         2016-10-24 23:42:11.143       2
```

For each one of the users I like to get the latest test score (month wise)  for the year broken down by month with their score. In other words,  I like to get the last score per user per month for a given year.

so for the above it would be

```
username       date                        testscore
mike           2016-11-30 23:41:10.143     1
john           2016-11-28 23:41:11.143     7 
mike           2016-10-30 23:41:10.143     1
john           2016-10-28 23:41:11.143     12
```

Comment: No Primary Key?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using the **WITH TIES** clause in concert with **Row_Number()**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 from YourTable
 Order by Row_Number() over (partition by UserName,year(date),month(date) order by date desc)
```

Returns

```
Username    date                    testscore
john        2016-10-28 23:41:11.143 12
john        2016-11-28 23:41:11.143 7
mike        2016-10-30 23:41:10.143 1
mike        2016-11-30 23:41:10.143 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY username, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),[date],112)
                                  ORDER BY [date] DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
select top 1 from <mytable> group by date.year(),date.month(),username order by date;
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you need a primary key, but you can still get the job done.

Essentially, you want the row for each username that corresponds to the latest date for that user.

```
SELECT username, date, testscore
FROM MyTable m1
WHERE m1.date = (SELECT MAX(m2.DATE)) 
                 FROM MyTable m2 
                 WHERE m2.username = m1.username)
```